# Set fileMode for *.sh When Copying Files To Tar By Convention

Tags: gradle

If I have a gradle file like this

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

version = '1.2'
 distributions {
    custom {}
}
```

By convention, all of the files in the “src/custom/dist” directory will automatically be included in the distribution. 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html

What if I want to set the fileMode on some of these files?

If I just specify the fileMode it doesn't do anything.

```
  into("") {
    from "src/custom/scripts"
    fileMode 0755
  }
```

EDIT: If I put the scripts in another dir and explicitly copy them (rather than them being copied by convention, the code below works.

```
distributions {
  custom {
    baseName = 'myApp'
    contents {
      into("") {
        from "src/external/scripts"
        fileMode 0755
      }
    }
  }
```

I am wondering if it is possible to have the files in the conventional place but change the attributes on some of the files.

Comment: From the [copy examples](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f490bdf61bd9b4f5383cd9fb0d8ffbca93da8c32/subprojects/core/src/integTest/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/CopyPermissionsIntegrationTest.groovy) I'm looking at, it is possible that fileMode needs to be set on the copy spec and not inside the `into` closure. Can you try moving it out of the closure?

Answer (score 1):

Following @RaGe link I came up with this:

```
distributions {
  custom {
    baseName = 'myApp'
    contents {
      //Other stuff
      eachFile { file ->
        if(file.getName().endsWith(".sh")) {
          file.setMode(0755)
      }
    }
  }
```